# K-Fold Cross-Validation How Many Folds?

Tags: data-science, cross-validation

Working with K-Fold Cross-Validation I commonly see 5 folds and 10 folds employed. A 1995 [paper](http://web.cs.iastate.edu/~jtian/cs573/Papers/Kohavi-IJCAI-95.pdf) recommends 10 fold cv. However that conclusion was based on small datasets using models of that time.

I'm just wondering if current use of 5 & 10 folds still harks back to that paper as a convention? Or are there are other good reasons to use 5 or 10 folds rather than say 6, 8, 12 etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just tradition. These are just nice numbers that people like and divide many things evenly. This works out to nice numbers like 10% and 20% each time. If you used 8, that would 12.5% each. Not as nice a number right?

It's possible for your dataset, another number works better, but it isn't worth the trouble to figure that out. If you tried to publish with 7-fold cross-validation, people would give you funny looks and become suspicious. Stick to the standards.

Answer (score 0):

K-Fold Cross Validation is helpful when the performance of your model shows significant variance based on your Train-Test split.

Using 5 or 10 is neither is a norm nor there is a rule. you  can use as many Folds (K= 2, 3, 4, to smart guess).

K fold cross validation is exploited to solve problems where Training data is limited .

I have came across an example in a book (Francois Chollet's book example shared below) where K=4 so it depend on your requirement.

```
enter code here

`k = 4
 num_validation_samples = len(data) // k
 np.random.shuffle(data)
 validation_scores = []
 for fold in range(k):
    validation_data = data[num_validation_samples * fold:
    num_validation_samples * (fold + 1)]
    training_data = data[:num_validation_samples * fold] +
    data[num_validation_samples * (fold + 1):
    model = get_model()
    model.train(training_data)
    validation_score = model.evaluate(validation_data)
    validation_scores.append(validation_score)
    validation_score = np.average(validation_scores)
model = get_model()
model.train(data)
test_score = model.evaluate(test_data)`
```

[Three-fold validation Pictorial Description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvH1H.png)